# basic fractal coloring problems

Tags: graphics, glsl, fractals

I am trying to get more comfortable with the math behind fractal coloring and understanding the coloring algorithms much better. I am the following paper:

http://jussiharkonen.com/files/on_fractal_coloring_techniques%28lo-res%29.pdf

The paper gives specific parameters to each of the functions, however when I use the same, my results are not quite right. I have no idea what could be going on though.

I am using the iteration count coloring algorithm to start and using the following julia set:

```
c = 0.5 + 0.25i and p = 2
```

with the coloring algorithm:

```
The coloring function simply returns the number of
elements in the truncated orbit divided by 20
```

And the palette function:

```
I(u) = k(u − u0),
where k = 2.5 and u0 = 0, was used.
```

And with a palette being white at 0 and 1, and interpolating to black in-between.

and following this algorithm:

1. Set z0 to correspond to the position of the pixel in the complex plane.
2. Calculate the truncated orbit by iterating the formula zn = f(zn−1) starting
   from z0 until either
   • |zn| > M, or
   • n = Nmax,
   where Nmax is the maximum number of iterations.
3. Using the coloring and color index functions, map the resulting truncated
   orbit to a color index value.
4. Determine an RGB color of the pixel by using the palette function

Using this my code looks like the following:

```
float izoom = pow(1.001, zoom );

vec2 z = focusPoint + (uv * 4.0 - 2.0)  * 1.0 / izoom;

vec2 c = vec2(0.5f, 0.25f) ;


const float B = 2.0;
float l;

for( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
{
     z = vec2( z.x*z.x - z.y*z.y, 2.0*z.x*z.y ) + c;

     if( length(z)>10.0) break;
     l++;

}
float ind = basicindex(l);
vec4 col = color(ind);
```

and have the following index and coloring functions:

```
float basicindex(float val){
    return val / 20.0;
}

vec4 color(float index){

    float r  = 2.5 * index;
    float g = r; 
    float b = g;
    vec3 v = 0.5 - 0.5 *  sin(3.14/2.0 + 3.14 * vec3(r, g, b));
    return vec4(1.0 - v, 1.0) ;

}
```

The paper provides the following image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjpcV.jpg

While my code produces:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny999.jpg

I get the correct results by using k = 1.0 instead of 2.5, however I would prefer to understand why my results are incorrect. When extending this to the smooth coloring algorithms, my results are still incorrect so I would like to figure this out first.

Let me know if this isn't the correct place for this kind of question and I can move it to the math stack exchange. I wasn't sure which place was more appropriate.

Comment: The two images are visually identical...

Comment: Also it would be nice to know the language you have used. I have no idea what length(z) means, complex radius?

Comment: Shoot,, for the "my image", 4 images got uploaded. The right one is the one that goes from white to black and them back to white.  Will update it in a few minutes.

Comment: Also this is glsl. Length is just the size of the vector (sqrt(x * x +y * y)) where x is the real component and y is the imaginary. Which I believe is the complex radius

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it needs some more clarification. I can barely make out the perspective code and identify it much less the language. But, my fiddling with Julia sets leads to the conclusion that there's an infinite number of ways to color them and some of them might look neat.

Comment: Ah yes, the perspective code is irrelevant for this. It just allows me to control the zoom and position. But all of that works and I do get the correct image. The coloring is what is in question. I am trying to get a better understanding of the math behind the coloring algorithms so that I am more comfortable expanding them/creating my own.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is perfectly implemented for Figure 3.3 in the paper. The other image you posted uses a different routine.

[image: figure 3.3]

Your figure seems to have that bit of perspective code there at top, but remove that and they should be the same.

[image: your result]

If your objection is the color extremes you set that with the "0.5 - 0.5 * ..." part of your code. This makes the darkest black originally 0.5 when in the example image you're trying to duplicate the darkest black should be 1 and the lightest white should be 0.

You're making the whiteness equal to the distance from 0.5

---

If you ignore the fractal all together you are getting a bunch of values that can be normalized between 0 and 1 and you're coloring those in some particular ways. Clearly the image you are duplicating is linear between 0 and 1 so putting black as 0.5 cannot be correct.

```js
o = {
    length : 500,
    width : 500,
    c : [.5, .25], // c = x + iy will be [x, y]
    maxIterate : 100,
    canvas : null
}

function point(pos, color){
    var c = 255 - Math.round((1 + Math.log(color)/Math.log(o.maxIterate)) * 255);
    c = c.toString(16);
    
    if (c.length == 1) c = '0'+c;
    o.canvas.fillStyle="#"+c+c+c;
    o.canvas.fillRect(pos[0], pos[1], 1, 1);
}

function conversion(x, y, R){
    var m = R / o.width;
    var x1 = m * (2 * x - o.width);
    var y2 = m * (o.width - 2 * y);
    return [x1, y2];
}

function f(z, c){
    return [z[0]*z[0] - z[1] * z[1] + c[0], 2 * z[0] * z[1] + c[1]];
}

function abs(z){
    return Math.sqrt(z[0]*z[0] + z[1]*z[1]);
}

function init(){
    var R = (1 + Math.sqrt(1+4*abs(o.c))) / 2,
        z, x, y, i;

    o.canvas = document.getElementById('a').getContext("2d");
    for (x = 0; x < o.width; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < o.length; y++){
            i = 0;
            z = conversion(x, y, R);
            while (i < o.maxIterate && abs(z) < R){
                z = f(z, o.c);
                if (abs(z) > R) break;
                i++;
            }
            

            if (i) point([x, y], i / o.maxIterate);
        }
    }
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="a" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

via: http://jsfiddle.net/3fnB6/29/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Although they are quite close, this is a different algorithm entirely. This algorithm is a step toward smooth coloring, and is not the raw iteration count algorithm. As you can see in my image there are clearly defined bands, while in the image you posted the bands are much softer.

Comment: To be more specific that is the "continuous iteration count" not the "iteration count" algorithm. Which will affect the range of the output which will have an impact on the colors being drawn. If I use this algorithm my results do not look like this image anymore.

Comment: Then the issue is where you bounce the values. That 0.5 - 0.5 * ... bit is going to make both extremes white. So your 0 is white and your 1 is white. As you've made black generally equal.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was intending for. Because the palate being used in the paper is exactly that.

Comment: I believe it is possibly a mistake in the paper. But I am not sure. It is just frustrating because when implementing the other algorithms I am not getting the correct results and I am not confident with the rest of my algorithm because my results are wrong for this as well.

Comment: Well if you ignore the fractal all together you are getting a bunch of values that can be normalized between 0 and 1 and you're coloring those in some particular ways. Clearly the image you are duplicating is linear between 0 and 1 so putting black as 0.5 cannot be correct.

Comment: Actually I am not sure this linear. If you look carefully there are small white dots inside the darkest areas. I believe it is because my algorithm's values increase too fast (due to the (2.5 * index)). In the one I am duplicating, their values may not be increasing to the point where they turn back to white. The paper also states that it is using a certain palette, which does have whites on both ends and black in the middle.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do the standard code and couldn't find any white specs in that particular fractal.

Comment: what do you mean by "i tried to do the standard code"

Comment: I edited a bit of Javascript into my answer for the set 0.5 .25i at 100 iterations and I don't see the white specs that show up in your version.

Comment: Wait, the coloring algorithm you are using doesn't seem like the iteration count coloring.

Comment: It is. By definition. The i value breaks and falls out of the loop then normalizes by the max i possible it's then normalized into a linear grey.

Comment: I see. Your code makes sense. I feel like the algorithm described in the paper isn't actually what is being used to generate the images. The algorithm described seems to be too naive. But i could be wrong.

Comment: Specifically using the parameters to the specific index and palette functions mentioned in the post. Which come directly from the paper as parameters for the images that I linked.

Comment: The code in the paper isn't generating the fractal it's colorizing the fractals. There's a lot of interesting stuff with that, but basically it'll give you a value between 0 and iterations for each pixel and then you do interesting things with that in a variety of ways. Though distance is a different metric etc.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the coloring algorithms. I am using a function to get a color based off the number of iterations. The paper claims "divide by 20 then multiply 2.5, the use that value to look into the palette" will give that drawing. Which is incorrect. I am specifically referring to coloring algorithms. Not the fractal equation in general. I could be wrong about what the paper is describing. Which is why I want to make sure I understand all of the components. My fractal equation should be correct, however when using their coloring algorithm I get inconsistent results.

Comment: Having read the paper, it's actually really really clever in that it uses some extra information at the iteration boundaries to make the discrete values within the fractal into much more continuous values where needed.

Comment: By iteration boundaries you are referring to 0 and max iterations? This term is never really defined in the paper

Comment: nevermind. I am stupid. The boundaries are just between colors change.

Comment: The Julia set is defined by the number of times at a particular point with particular values it can iterate without exceeding the threshold R. As a consequence of this the values within the Julia set are integers. So it has these very visible bands. What the paper is doing is showing that right at those bands you can still create a continuous gradient with some math with the value of R at the two different iterations. At the cusps of those bands the value is perfect, but you can see between the two values of R at the two iterations a way to smooth it out.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. Each iteration is a discrete value, and so the point where it is equal to the boundary will end up being a fraction. So it instead of something taking lets say 22 iterations, it may be taking 21.x to get the boundary. But this information is lost to the discrete nature of the formula.

Comment: This helped a lot by the way. Even though my original question was answered I feel better about things. I think I just need to slow down and really understand the paper properly.

Comment: So where the transitions happen the values are decidedly right, so it solves within that band for the interpolated values of which band they are closest by some clever maths to get the partial iterations.